# Angular 4 ngFor variable to hold value

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
<div>{{item.subArray[0].attr1}}</div>
<div>{{item.subArray[0].attr2}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Is there a way to create a variable for item.subArray[0], instead of accessing the 0th element over and over. For example:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let subItem = item.subArray[0]">
<div>{{subItem.attr1}}</div>
<div>{{subItem.attr2}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You would need to do another ngFor inside the ng-container, looping over the subArray.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just nest another iterator:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of item.subArray">
    <div>{{subItem.attr1}}</div>
    <div>{{subItem.attr2}}</div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What if he doesn't want to loop over `item.subArray`, but only use `item.subArray[0]`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan In my understanding OP _explicitly does not_ want to do that, from _"instead of accessing the 0th element over and over"_, and that the inclusion of that `item.subArray[0]` the what-if example code is simply a wrong attempt. I invite OP to clarify, of course. :)